# Browser downloading instead of processing .cfm files

Tags: coldfusion-10

I am using ColdFusion 10 (I don't know why the company hasn't upgraded) and after the initial installation of ColdFusion I can get to the web pages, but instead of opening, they download. I've been at this for hours. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling IIS. The setup is on a Windows 10 machine for development purposes. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This sounds a bit more like a setup issue than a programming issue.  As such, this probably should be in ServerFault.

Comment: I suggest you talk to your team. Don't they have development environment setup instructions?

Comment: ServerFault is a better fit. That said, it's often due to connector problems.  Have a look at this thread for ideas.  Also, since it's an old version, pay attention to versions 32/64 bit. https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/iis-and-coldfusion-11-displaying-cfm-pages-as-html/m-p/9915893

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to configure IIS connectors via the Wsconfig tool to add your application (as an administrator)?

Path to the tool for example is here.
C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\runtime\bin\wsconfig.exe